# Second highest value by department using Apache Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table where `department` and `value` is available now if we will use SQL query to achieve the output of second highest value by each department then we write like:

```
select * from (SELECT department, asset_value, DENSE_RANK() over (partition by DEPARTMENT order by ASSET_VALUE) as x from [User1].[dbo].[UsersRecord]) y where x = 2;
```

But, in Apache Spark, if we have a restriction to not to use the SparkSQL and we have to achieve the output using DataFrame only then how we should write the Scala code?

I tried from my end by taking the help of the Documentation but could not figure it out.

My Code:

```
package com.tg.testpack1

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.row_number
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object class2
{
 def main(args: Array[String]) 
 {
    val sparksessionobject = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:/Users/ox/spark/spark/spark-warehouse")
      .getOrCreate()
    sparksessionobject.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 4)
    sparksessionobject.conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    import sparksessionobject.sqlContext.implicits._

val df = Seq(("DEPT1", 1000), ("DEPT1", 500), ("DEPT1", 700), ("DEPT2", 400), ("DEPT2", 200),  ("DEPT3", 500), ("DEPT3", 200))
         .toDF("department", "assetValue")

df.withColumn("col3", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy($"department").orderBy($"assetValue".desc))).show
}
}
```

I am getting the output:

```
+-------------+----------+----+
|accountNumber|assetValue|col3|
+-------------+----------+----+
|        DEPT3|       500|   1|
|        DEPT3|       200|   2|
|        DEPT1|      1000|   1|
|        DEPT1|       700|   2|
|        DEPT1|       500|   3|
|        DEPT2|       400|   1|
|        DEPT2|       200|   2|
+-------------+----------+----+
```

I am expecting the output:

```
+-------------+----------+----+
|accountNumber|assetValue|col3|
+-------------+----------+----+
|        DEPT1|       700|   2|
|        DEPT2|       200|   2|
|        DEPT3|       200|   2|
+-------------+----------+----+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify your code as below :

```
val byDeptOrderByAssetDesc = Window
  .partitionBy($"department")
  .orderBy($"assetValue" desc)
df.withColumn("col3", dense_rank() over byDeptOrderByAssetDesc)
  .filter("col3=2")
```

Comment: what if i dont have col3 values?

Comment: In that case you can create a ranking column based on ordering of other two columns and then add the filter at the end